# Is Vaikuntha or Brahman the supreme abode of Vishnu per Vishnu Purana?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, advaita, vishnu-purana, vaikuntha

Vishnu Purana is one of the primary texts of Vaishnavism. It's the authority over Vaishnavism.

Does it talk about Vaikutha? If not what it says regarding the highest abode of Vishnu? Does it uphold the Advaitik abode of Vishnu that is formless and not perceptible or Vaikuntha?

Comment: yes dear, vaikuntha is the abode of krishna and in that abode there are pure clean souls that live with krishna singing his glories . and there are the doorkeepers in vaikuntha that is jaya and vijaya. they only allow devotees that are properly dressed and pure souls that are chanting krishna name to enter into vaikuntha whereas they dont allow non devotees to enter vaikuntha because they dont care of spiritual world and for non devotees they think material things so thats why the doorkeepers have blocked their way and so they fall back into material world.

Answer (score 4):

The supreme abode of Vishnu is *non-dualistic* in nature as mentioned in Vishnu Purana. In my reading, I found that Vaikuntha word is absent in Vishnu Purana. And while reading it I came across this verse.

> यत्तदव्यक्तमजरमचिन्त्यमजमव्ययम् । अनिर्देश्यमरूपं च पाणिपादाद्यसंयुतम् ॥६६॥
>   विभुः सर्वगतं नित्यं भूतयोनिरकारणम् । व्याप्यव्याप्तं यतः सर्वं यद्वै पश्यन्ति सूरयः ॥६७॥
>   तद्ब्रह्मतत्परं धाम तद्धयेयं मोक्षकाङ्क्षभिः। श्रुतिवाक्योदितं सूक्ष्मं तद्विष्णोः परमं पदम् ॥६८॥
>
> That which is
>   imperceptible, undecaying, inconceivable, unborn, inexhaustible,
>   ***indescribable***; **which has neither form**, nor hands, nor feet; which is
>   almighty, **omnipresent**, eternal; the cause of all things, and without
>   cause; permeating all, itself unpenetrated, and from which all things
>   proceed; that is the object which the wise behold, *that is Brahman*,
>   that is the supreme state, that is the subject of contemplation to
>   those who desire liberation, that is the thing spoken of by the Vedas,
>   the infinitely subtle, supreme abode of Vishnu (तद्विष्णो: परमं पदं)-- ***Vishnu Purana - 6.5.66-68***

This verse is quite explicit and it leaves no doubt that formless Brahman is the supreme abode or state of Vishnu.

The above translation is based on [Sanskrit-Hindi Vishnu Purana](https://archive.org/stream/puran_vishnu/Vishnu#page/n440/mode/1up)

Source: [English translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp160.htm).

Comment: Good answer but formless doesn't alone guarantee Advaitic nature. Nirguna Brahman in Advaita is without attributes. Nirakara and Nirguna are two different things in Advaita. btw, welcome to Hinduism SE.

Comment: @TheDestroyer But nirguna Brahman is often described by negating attributes. Negation is used here in that verse to indicate the supreme Abode of Vishnu. Form is an attribute here and it has been negated by formless word. Anyway can you tell me how to contact moderators? I'm not able to comment on posts.

Comment: Yes. Nirguna Braman is often described by negation. On Stack Exchange sites you get privileges by reputation. For beta sites (i.e, this site) [see this page](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) . You need reputation of 50 to comment and 20 to participate in chat.

Comment: "...that is the thing spoken of by the Vedas, the infinitely subtile, supreme **condition** of Vishńu." Any specific reason behind _altering_ the word 'condition' from [source you linked](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp160.htm) and quoting it as 'abode' in your answer!?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Well, refer Sanskrit verses. "Padam" means abode

Comment: Yes. I would suggest adding the sanskrit verse(s) and mentioning you have changed the quote based on said sanskrit verses. Right now, this alteration is not clear and seems as if the answer were directly quoting the source.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan okay! Let me add the Sanskrit source. It's just that I couldn't find the other English source for this Purana. Sacred text translation is filled with spelling mistakes and other issues.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Done! And anyway the Brahman being the supreme condition of Vishnu is also Advaitik.

Comment: In the Advaitic sense both seem synonymous as you yourself have put it. In any case, people can still mistake your block quote(as it is without any disclaimers) to mean that it is a quoted translation rather than a modified one.

Comment: I've added Sanskrit verses 66-68 of which translation is quoted.